# Collection<T> is read-only?! What's the matter with using the params keyword to instantiate a collection?

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, parameters, readonly

I'm using Unity version 2023.1.6. I have a custom collection that inherits from `Collection<T>`. If I instantiate a collection and then try to use the `.Add()` method I receive the following error :

```
System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].Add (T item) [0x0000d] in <46a5f68c38604d68a85231bbf55f6b8f>:0
```

I noticed that this error occurs only if I instantiate the collection using this constructor:

```
public Selection(params T[] selectionElements) : base(selectionElements) { }
```

I fixed the error by changing the constructor to this:

```
public Selection(params T[] selectionElements) : base(selectionElements.ToList()) { }
```

I don't know what LINQ does behind the scenes and even why this works (I just tried...),  so I remain with a few more questions:

- What's the problem with using the `params` keyword?
- Does `params` create an array? If yes, why it's not ok to pass in an array as an `IList<T>`? If it's not ok why there is no compile time error?
- Why the LINQ method fixed the error?

Comment: as you see in the methods signature `params` allways is an array-type, which is immutable. A `List<T>` on ther other hand can easily be modified using `Add`. This is why `ToList` (which is not really a linq-function, btw) "fixes" that error.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain: nitpick: "(which is not really a linq-function)" [`Enumerable.ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-7.0) is a linq method, as every method in the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-7.0) class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no problem using the `params` keyword, the problem is passing an array as an `IList` and expecting to be able to add to it. This is an example of the C# base class library not doing the best job with the Liskov Substitution Principle (the 'L' in SOLID).

`IList<T>` contains an 'IsReadOnly' property. An `Array<T>` implements `IList<T>`, but of course you can't add to an array - you would need to copy all the contents into a larger one first, which is exactly the job that `List<T>` does. The `IsReadOnly` property is *true*, and if you try to call `Add()` it will throw an exception.

A separate `IReadOnlyList<T>` was added later on to make it more obvious what's going on, but `Array<T>` still implements the original `IList<T>` interface for the sake of backwards compatibility.

Why does this work when you call `selectionElements.ToList()`? `ToList()` does the following:

- Creates a new `List<T>`
- Enumerates the array
- Adds each item from the array to the new list
- Returns the list

This means that you now have a `List<T>` with all the same values in it, which implements `IList<T>` and importantly is not read-only

Comment: Strictly speaking, we should have *three* interfaces, `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IReplaceableList<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IExpandableList<T> : IReplaceableList<T>` with arrays only implementing the first two. It's not just backwards compatibility, `IReadOnlyList<T>` is not writeable *at all* whereas arrays are.

Comment: @Charlieface I agree, but I don't know if the language would support `IReadOnlyList<T>` defining the 'get' indexer and `IReplaceableList<T>` defining the 'set' indexer. This is where languages like Rust and Val have a one-up, having language support for mutable/readonly instances and references would make this a moot point.

Comment: Yeah bit of a mess at this point https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/1982

Answer (score 3):

That behavior is simply because `Array` implements `IList` for convenience.

Once you realize that, it's obvious why `Add` fails, i.e. it's not a list.

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var list = new[] { 1 };

    var collection = new Collection<int>(list);

    collection.Add(1); // System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.
}
```

LINQ works because it creates an `IList` out of the `Array`, i.e. it's modifiable:

```
public void TestMethod2()
{
    var list = new [] { 1 };

    var collection = new Collection<int>(list.ToList()); // not above array anymore

    collection.Add(1); // works
}
```